# Change screen size in PyBox2D

Tags: box2d, python

I would like to use `pybox2d`'s `Framework` class to visualize the simulation. However, the default screen / windows size is 640 x 480 pixels and I don't find a way to change it. I would like to know how I can change the screen size. The code below is a minimal working example:

[image]

```
from Box2D.examples.framework import Framework, main
from Box2D import b2EdgeShape, b2FixtureDef, b2PolygonShape, b2Vec2, b2Color


class TestObject(Framework):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TestObject, self).__init__()

        # World
        self.world.gravity = (0.0, -10.0)
        self.world.CreateStaticBody(
            shapes=[
                    b2EdgeShape(vertices=[(-10, 0), (10, 0)]),
                    b2EdgeShape(vertices=[(-10, 0), (-20, 20)]),
                    b2EdgeShape(vertices=[(10, 0), (20, 20)]),
                ]
        )

        obj_vertices = [(0.5, 0.5), (-0.5, 0.5), (-0.5, -0.5), (0.5, -0.5)]

        # Create object
        position = b2Vec2(12, 20)
        linear_velocity = (0.0, -10.0)
        self.obj = self.world.CreateDynamicBody(position=position, linearVelocity=linear_velocity, allowSleep=False)

        density = 1
        height, width = 6, 4
        vertices = [(width * item[0], height * item[1]) for item in obj_vertices]
        shape = b2PolygonShape(vertices=vertices)
        fixture_def = b2FixtureDef(shape=shape, density=density)
        self.obj.CreateFixture(fixture_def)

    def Step(self, settings):
        super(TestObject, self).Step(settings)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(TestObject)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not used this framework before, so this is untested, but looking at the code, I would try this first:

One way to go appears to by modify the file [`pybox2d/library/Box2D/examples/backends/pygame_framework.py`](https://github.com/pybox2d/pybox2d/blob/f8617198555d2e1539b0be82f0ee6e7db4d26085/library/Box2D/examples/backends/pygame_framework.py#L238), where it calls `pygame.display.set_mode` (or [`pybox2d/library/Box2D/examples/backends/opencv_framework.py`](https://github.com/pybox2d/pybox2d/blob/f8617198555d2e1539b0be82f0ee6e7db4d26085/library/Box2D/examples/backends/opencv_framework.py#L204) where it defines the ctor  `def __init__(self, w=640, h=480, resizable=False)`) and set the size you want, but I presume this is a hackish way to do it.

It could get you going for the tests you're doing.

If you need a "cleaner" way, *maybe* what you need to do it is to clone the `pybox2d/library/Box2D/examples/backends/pygame_framework.py` file and implement the `w=640, h=480` in the ctor like it's being done in the other backend, then you would pass the values at object construction in your own test code.

It seems the way to integrate a Framework with a Backend is described at the end of [framework.py](https://github.com/pybox2d/pybox2d/blob/f8617198555d2e1539b0be82f0ee6e7db4d26085/library/Box2D/examples/framework.py#L522),

```
# Your framework classes should follow this format. If it is the 'foobar'
# framework, then your file should be 'backends/foobar_framework.py' and you
# should have a class 'FoobarFramework' that subclasses FrameworkBase. Ensure
# proper capitalization for portability.
from Box2D.examples import backends

try:
    framework_name = '%s_framework' % (fwSettings.backend.lower())
    __import__('backends', globals(), fromlist=[framework_name], level=1)
    framework_module = getattr(backends, framework_name)
    Framework = getattr(framework_module,
                        '%sFramework' % fwSettings.backend.capitalize())
except Exception as ex:
    print('Unable to import the back-end %s: %s' % (fwSettings.backend, ex))
    print('Attempting to fall back on the pygame back-end.')

    from Box2D.examples.backends.pygame_framework import PygameFramework as Framework
```

This may not be the complete/right solution but I hope it will help you get started finding it. And whenever you find it, please don't hesitate to write an answer to this question and mark it as accepted :)

Comment: I agree though that this is a "bug" that could be worth an update to `pygame_framework.py` and a pull request to the repository.